# I invited them and no one came

Tags: anagram

My colleague told me this morning with frustration: To 200 friends I sent invitations to my birthday party,   and not one person came. The last paragraph of the invitation had a mysterious sentence which read, ″Renty grache sound tahar dolls″ . What did he meant by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He meant:

> Entry charge thousand dollars

This also explains why nobody came.

I solved this by:

> 1. Renty is an anagram of entry

> 2. grache is an anagram of charge

> 3. sound tahar dolls is an anagram of thousand dollars

> 4. So the complete message is **Entry charge thousand dollars**

Comment: You're quite sure it's not because of the sub-standard wine they're serving? I hear they have a GHASTLY AND HORRENDOUS CLARET... ;-)

Comment: The tag kinda gave the answer away

Comment: That entry charge plus the fine because of gathering with so many people at Covid times... no wonder nobody came :-)